# How to sum up the values in a column with Python when the column has multiple data types

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to add all the numbers in a specific column together and my current code throws an error because the column also contains non-numeric data. For example, the data looks like this:

```
Values

NaN
NaN
0
NoData
无
1200
NaN
2300
```

In this case, I just need the sum of 1200 and 2300 but the current code generates an error because the column also contains NaN and Strings, both English and Foreign characters. How do I update the code to resolve the issue?

```
summary = 0
for i in range(c+1, b-2):
    if not pd.isna(df.loc[i]['Values']) or not isinstance(df.loc[i]['Values'], str): 
        item_sum += df.loc[i]['Values']
```

The current data type of the Value column is "object".

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at [`pandas.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is wrong. You are checking if the value is not `NaN` *or* the value is not a `str`, which will always be true because there is no value that is both `NaN` and a `str`. Switch to `and`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this without looping:

```
pd.to_numeric(df['Values'], errors='coerce').sum()
```

Output:

```
3500.0
```

If series contains 'INF', the what do you want to happen?  Intrepet INF as infinite, do same.

```
pd.to_numeric(df['Values'], errors='coerce').sum()
```

Output:

```
inf
```

or ignore 'INF' then use replace like @BrendanA suggests:

```
pd.to_numeric(df['Values'].replace('INF', np.nan), errors='coerce').sum()
```

Output:

```
3500.00
```

Comment: What if an entry is `INF`?

Comment: Use this line before the to_numeric function `df['Values'].replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan, inplace=True)`